# How do I SSH into my Nvidia Jetson TX2 from Ubuntu VM on Windows using an ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, ethernet

I have a TX2 Ubuntu Machine directly connected to my Windows laptop via ethernet cable. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on VMWare. How do I allow the Ubuntu VM on my laptop to use the ethernet port so I can SSH into the TX2? I can't even ping it.
I tried creating another network adapter (Bridged type which replicates physical network connection state).

Answer (score 1):

On a clean tx2, the box needs a DHCP server to issue an IP.  Simply plugging your computer into the tx2 won't get you very far.  Without knowing how your windows box or vm environment are configured, you may need to configure a dhcp server on your windows box in order to issue the IP.  For simplicity, I highly recommend using a tool like [tftpd32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html).

Once DHCP is configured and an IP is issued to the device, you can easily lookup what IP was issued to the TX2 and simply ssh to that IP.  (use ubuntu as the username and nvidia as the password)

On a side note, you won't be able to use the JetPack to re-flash a tx2 within a VM.  (unfortunately)  There are issues with device drivers and timings that don't work, even if you do pass the usb hardware to the VM.

Comment: I should clarify. This TX2 is already set up. I can SSH into it from the Windows Terminal. I just need to be able to SSH into it from my Ubuntu VM. Thanks for the Flashing tip! I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bridged network adapter in VMWare so that your guest OS can connect directly to the same network your laptop is on. Then you will be able to connect ssh via the IP address of the TX2. Make sure you bridge to the wired network interface.

Comment: As @Andy said, the bridged-network adapter will work fine in VMware, but in virtualbox, you can use a NATed interface, and/or a bridged interface.  Just make sure the bridged interface is bound to the interface that the TX2 is on.  Just don't use the "host-only" interface.  In any case, more info about which VM environment you are using would be helpful.

Comment: who hands out the dhcp leases? The Question mentions a direct connection via ethernet.

Comment: in bridged-mode, the same thing that issues an IP to the windows box.  In NAT mode, virtualbox has a built-in DHCP server for NAT'd devices.

Comment: I believe I have done this already but can you help me verify?

Comment: You should be able to find tutorials or documentation online to verify you have configured the right mode. For example: https://geek-university.com/vmware-player/configure-bridged-networking/

Answer (score 0):

What sort of DHCP server are you running i.e on what device?

Have you tried putting the current adapter in bridge mode. Also do you have your windows laptop connected to another network i.e wifi? if so do you need it to be connected to that network?. I would try installing a dhcp server on windows so your windows laptop hands out ip addresses to itself, the VM connected using a bridge adapter and the TX2 Ubuntu machine via the ethernet port.

EDIT:

Your DHCP server is most probably running on your router which you are connected through wifi. If you connect the tx2 box directly into the router which is most likely the same device which is running your wifi your tx2 box will get an ip on your network in the same range as your wifi devices i.e laptop and vm running on it.

By bridge mode I meant in your vm setting under network you can set it as NAT or Bridge when you set it as bridge your VM will get a local ip directly from the router which will be the same range as your laptop.

With the above setup you should be able to SSH using the local IP addresses handed out from your network router and should also have internet connectivity on all the devices.

If you want to connect your TX2 directly into your Windows machine then the issue of DHCP servers arises. You will need your Windows laptop to be the dhcp server by installing the software for it. But that might cause problems with getting internet on all the devices as the wifi network will be in a different range with a different DHCP server and IP range.

Comment: How do I check what sort of DHCP server I am running? When you say "putting the current adapter in bridge mode," do you mean from Windows or the Ubuntu VM? Yes my laptop is connected to WiFi. Yes I need to be connected to it.

Comment: on linux ifconfig, on windows ipconfig. It is usually the gateway or the first one in the range of ips i.e if your linux machine is 192.168.10.20 then check which device has 192.168.10.1. Do you have a router in this setup then most probably that is handing out the dhcp leases.